# Определить как часто каждое слово встречается в тексте

Tags: c++

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct word
{
    char value[25];
    int number;
};


int main()
{
    char str[100], str1[100];
    int i = 0, k = 0;
    FILE* file, *file1, *file2;

    if ((file = fopen("text.txt", "r")) == NULL)
    {
        puts("Error");
        exit(1);
    }

    while (fgets(str, 100, file) == NULL);

    fclose(file);
    char* ptr = strtok(str, ",.-!?");

    while (ptr != NULL)
    {
        cout << ptr;

        if ((file1 = fopen("new.txt", "a")) == NULL)
        {
            puts("Error");
            exit(1);
        }

        fputs(ptr, file1);
        fclose(file1);
        ptr = strtok(NULL, ",.-!?");
    }

    cout << endl;
    cout << "ZZZ" << endl;

    if ((file2 = fopen("new.txt", "r")) == NULL)
    {
        puts("Error");
        exit(1);
    }

    fgets(str1, 100, file2);

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        if (str1[i] == ' ')
            k++;
    }

    cout << "AAA" << endl;
    cout << "The number of the words = " << k + 1 << endl;
    fclose(file2);
    word* d = new word[k];

    if ((file2 = fopen("new.txt", "r")) == NULL)
    {
        puts("Error");
        exit(1);
    }

    while (fscanf(file2, "%s", d[i].value) != EOF)
    {
        i++;
    }

    fclose(file2);

    for (int i = 0; i < k + 1; i++)
    {
        cout << d[i].value << endl;
    }

    cout << "ZZZ" << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < k + 1; i++) 
{
    for (int j = 1; j < k + 1; j++)
    {
        d[i].number = 1;
        if (i != j) {
            if (strcmp(d[i].value, d[j].value) == 0)
                d[i].number++;
        }
        }
}
for (int i = 0; i < k + 1; i++) 
cout << "The number of word which are the same with "<< d[i].value<<    d[i].number << endl;

    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Не показывает количество каждого слова, выдает -8513...

Comment: Думаю, можно попробовать воспользоваться мощью регулярных выражений - код будет намного компактнее. Но при этом не факт, что будет работать быстрее, выглядеть понятнее и нагляднее.

Answer (score 0):

У вас же C++ - помещаем слова в `string`, чтоб компаратор не писать, и используем `map<string,int>` - все, задача решена...

Набросок:

```
int main()
{

    ifstream in("test.cpp");

    string s;
    map<string,int> m;
    while(in >> s)
    {
        m[s]++;
    }

    for(auto x: m)
    {
        cout << "Word: " << setw(30) << x.first 
             << ": count = " << setw(5) << x.second << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Очистку слов от мусора (точек и прочих знаков препинания) допишите сами.

**Update** Раз нужно помучиться, укажу на самые очевидные ошибки.
Итак, вы выделили массив `d`. Что в нем? Мусор. Все `d[i].number` содержат в прямом смысле что угодно. Вы их не обнуляете перед работой!

Более того, при работе вы с ними тоже ничего не делаете, не считать же

```
if (strcmp(d[i].value, d[j].value) == 0)
    d[i].number + 1;
```

изменением значения `d[i].number` - вы просто прибавляете к нему 1 и выбрасываете то, что получилось...

Для начала исправьте эти ошибки.

Comment: я студент, и мне надо это сделать в процедурном стиле.

Comment: Ну, тогда см. дополнение к моему ответу...

Comment: я исправил вот как получилось

Comment: мусора нет но считает неправильно

Comment: @yra1029, у вас там кроме этой ещё ошибок вагон. BTW, не надо ждать когда вам всё разжуют и в рот положат: возьмите отдладчик, прошагайте в нём свою программу и увидите своими глазами что и как там происходит.